# Why do I get no result with this block?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a function that should return the first and last name from a full name, it's like this:

```
create or replace package body pkg_format_eagle_data as
    function parse_firstname(p_fullname supplier.contactname%type) return varchar2 is
        v_firstname supplier.contactname%type;
    begin
        v_firstname := substr(p_fullname,1,instr(p_fullname,' ',1,1)-1);
        return v_firstname;
    end PARSE_FIRSTNAME;

    function PARSE_LASTNAME(p_fullname supplier.contactname%type) return varchar2 is
        v_lastname supplier.contactname%type;
    begin
        v_lastname := substr(p_fullname,instr(p_fullname,' ',1,1)+1,length(p_fullname) - instr(p_fullname,' ',1,1));
    return v_lastname;
    end PARSE_LASTNAME;
end pkg_format_eagle_data;
```

It compiled successfully, but when I call it in the following block, it returns nothing. In this block, I created a variable called fullName to store the cursor, and loop through the cursor.

```
declare 
fullName supplier.contactname%type;

cursor list_supplier is
select contactname 
from supplier;

begin
open list_supplier;
loop
    fetch list_supplier into fullName;
    dbms_output.put(pkg_format_eagle_data.PARSE_FIRSTNAME(fullName));
    dbms_output.put_line(pkg_format_eagle_data.PARSE_LASTNAME(fullName));
    exit when list_supplier%notfound;
end loop;
close list_supplier;
end;
```

I've tried the condition of function in SELECT and they work. May I ask that where I made a mistake? Here's a sample table:

```
create table supplier
(
    contactname varchar2(50);
);

INSERT INTO supplier (contactname)
VALUES ('Alice Bob');
INSERT INTO supplier (contactname)
VALUES ('Tim Tom');
INSERT INTO supplier (contactname)
VALUES ('Sam Bob');
```

Comment: Which client are you using, and did you do `set serveroutput on` or the equivalent for that client? (Your `exit` check should be immediately after `fetch`, incidentally, but that will just produce a duplicate final output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have verified your code in Oracle DB and it's output is shown below.

```
AliceBob
TimTom
SamBob
SamBob
```

Which is as expected except that the repeated lines are due to the placement of `exit`, which should come immediately after fetch statement.

Only reason I can think of you missing to `set serveroutput on` if its SQL* Plus or equivalent in any other tool you are using.